# How to hide searchview searchicon

Tags: android

Im trying to hide icon this icon in the searchview:

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
  ((ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null)))
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

I can't figure it out why it is not working since I used the same code to hide close icon and it works fine:

```
    ((ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null)))
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Is the identifier for search icon good?

Answer (score 0):

maybe (probably) this icon is invalidated (redrawn) sometimes with setting new `LayoutParams` (overwritting yours). you should check (look) in Android source code, but there is simpler solution to try - instead of setting new params maybe try to set transparent drawable, which might be created using `new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

if this identifier is wrong you should get `NullPointerException`

also: for checking `View` params or (and) ids you may use `Hierarchy Viewer`, which dump whole screen of your device (emulator). more [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) (and in Google)

(lot of brackets)